# I want to count number of page breaks in my wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

The code for my wordpress post to show in my single.php page the following array that I have used. I want to check for the number of page breaks that I have put inside a  wordpress post. Such That I want to add a previous and  a next button link inside apost in my wordpress admin.

```
           <?php 
          $args = array(
          'before'           => '<div class="page-link-next-prev">',
           'after'            => '</div>',
           'link_before'      => '',
           'link_after'       => '',
           'next_or_number'   => 'next',
           'nextpagelink'     => __('<div class="next">Continue Reading</div>'),
           'previouspagelink' => __('<div class="prev">Go Back</div>'),
           'pagelink'         => '%',
           'more_file'        => '');

           wp_link_pages($args); 
           ?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the number of page breaks always be the number of pages - 1?

Answer (score 0):

Use php count() function as in count($pages).

I would store it as a variable such as:
$num_of_pages = count($pages);

You can then use it for what you want.